I have no idea what error I am going through.. Can anyone explain how to fix this problem?
enter image description here
The sign error. I have no idea what error I am going through.
I have tried it for several times, even reinstalled visual studio for Mac twice. But the problem wasn't solved.
I tried following the YouTube but still couldn't get the same result.
Please help me. Thank you.

Welcome to Stackoverflow. Questions containing only pictures of the problem
are rarely answered and usually closed. See Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?
and the answer

This command:

gcc hello.c -o hello

is failing with _main symbol not found for arm64.
This means that your machine is misconfigured. In particular, you probably have a mismatched gcc and ld, with the latter expecting arm64 object code, and the former is producing something else (perhaps x86_64).
To figure out what's going on, run these commands:
gcc --version
ld --version

gcc -c hello.c
file hello.o

This should show what architecture(s) gcc and ld are configured for, and what object file gcc produced.

even reinstalled visual studio for Mac twice

The Visual Studio is using gcc that you have probably installed separately (and for the wrong target architecture). But this is just a guess.
